# How do I get a .so file from a .la file?

Tags: gcc, fftw

FFTW 2.x builds a .la file (under fftw/.libs directory).

I think I need a .so file to link to. (I am not sure, because I am a gcc newbie).

Comment: Any particular reason you're using such an old version of FFTW ?

Comment: I couldn't get the 3.x version to build at all on my machine. Something in the "tests" directory made it fail. Cant remember exact problem now, but 2.x built fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general on Linux, a .so file is dynamic library and a .a or .la is for statically linking with.  Which one you need depends on your application and how you installed/built the library.  For a tutorial on static vs. dynamic linking see [this site.](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html) Also, did you build fftw yourself from source, or did you use a package manager? This would help answer your question.  As for using gcc, check out this [manual page](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_25.html), it might clear some stuff up.

So yeah, the short answer is either to stick with the .a or when building fftw specify that you want a shared library. `./configure --enable-shared`

Comment: the other libs i use are all .so and are linked to using -lpython2.4 for instance, where i have a libpython2.4.so.0.0.0

Comment: Well, in that case, when you compile the library you need to specify 'shared' and not 'static'.  If you are using a distro like unbuntu or fedora, then just use the package manager and install the -devel package.

When building add --enable-shared when you call ./configure
From the fftw manual. http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Installation-on-Unix.html#Installation-on-Unix